# MySQL change composite primary key to surrogate

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `my_table` (with existing data) with a composite primary key on `(dealer_id, model_id, model_year, allocation_week)` where `dealer_id` and `model_id` are both foreign keys to the `model` and `dealer` tables. There is no single unique column in `my_table`. I want to add a new surrogate primary key, using

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

This fails with error `1068 Multiple primary key defined`.

So I try dropping the existing (composite) primary key with:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

This fails, saying `errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

How can I replace the composite key with a surrogate key?

Comment: Why not remove your composite primary key first, and after create primary key, add it back?

Comment: It sounds like you have some foreign key from another table referencing your current composite primary key, and it complains when you try to drop the primary key constraint.

Comment: Oh, I just thought -- a foreign key must have an index backing it. If the `dealer_id` (the leftmost column of your primary key) was relying on the primary key as its  backing index, it will break the foreign key when you drop the PK.

Comment: @TonyDong That's what the second statement is attempting, but it fails, complaining about a malformed foreign key constraint.

Comment: @BillKarwin The schema visualizer doesn't indicate anything referencing it and I don't think there is anything that would be. The index thing is a great insight. I'll look into that.

Comment: As you have FK to model and dealer tables you must have indexes on your dealer_id and model_id columns. Right now index on dealer_id is not mandatory as it is the leftmost column in your PK. However, if you are going to drop the PK, you have to create index on dealer_id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing the error:

```
mysql> create table dealers (dealer_id int primary key);
mysql> create table models (model_id int primary key);
mysql> create table my_table (dealer_id int, model_id int, model_year int, allocation_week int, primary key (dealer_id, model_id, model_year, allocation_week));

mysql> alter table my_table add foreign key (dealer_id) references dealers(dealer_id);

mysql> alter table my_table add foreign key (model_id) references models (model_id);
```

Now the table looks like this. It implicitly created an index for `model_id`, but it didn't have to do that for `dealer_id` because it was able to "borrow" the use of the PK index for the leftmost column.

```
mysql> show create table my_table\G

CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `dealer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `model_year` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allocation_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dealer_id`,`model_id`,`model_year`,`allocation_week`),
  KEY `model_id` (`model_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dealer_id`) REFERENCES `dealers` (`dealer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `models` (`model_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

So when I drop the PK, it can't do it because that would break the FK:

```
mysql> alter table my_table drop primary key;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-337_18' to './test/my_table' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
```

Solution: add a secondary index for the `dealer_id`, then you can drop the PK.

You can do all these changes in one ALTER:

```
mysql> alter table my_table 
    add key (dealer_id), 
    drop primary key, 
    add column id int auto_increment primary key first;
```

Result:

```
mysql> show create table my_table\G

CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dealer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `model_year` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allocation_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `model_id` (`model_id`),
  KEY `dealer_id` (`dealer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dealer_id`) REFERENCES `dealers` (`dealer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `models` (`model_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```